# How to name transaction in mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, mariadb

In sql we can name the transactions but seems like it doesn't work in mariadb. Or am i wrong?

I use nodeJs mariadb. I want:

1. create connection
2. start transaction (in first function)
3. run some sql queries (in second function)
4. do rollback (in third function)

currently it doesn't work, i think cause i should use transaction name for rollback. Savepoints is useless in this case.

Comment: In MySQL/MariaDB you cannot set a name to the transaction. But it's not necessary or useful. You may create and use transactional savepoints if needed. See [SAVEPOINT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/savepoint/).

Comment: What do you hope to achieve? Start with the objective, not the non-existent solution.